# How to derive consumer expenditures in EMEA 14.2.5

Tags: mathematical-economics, consumer-theory, self-study, lagrangian

I am working on a problem 14.2.5 from EMEA by Sydsaeter, Hammond and Strom.

> Consider the consumer demand problem:
> $$ \max_{x,y} U(x,y) = \alpha \ln(x-a) + \beta \ln(y-b) \text{ s.t. } px+qy=m \tag{*} $$
> where $\alpha, \beta, a, b, p, q$ and $m$ are positive constants with $\alpha + \beta =1 $, and moreover, with $m>ap+bq$. Show that if $x^*, y^*$ solve problem (*),  then expenditure on the two goods is given by the two linear functions:
> $$ px^*= \alpha m+ pa -\alpha(pa+qb), qy^* = \beta m+ qb - \beta (pa + qb)$$

My attempt:

I set up Lagrangian:

$$ L= \alpha \ln(x-a) + \beta \ln(y-b) - \lambda (px+qy-m) $$

and get FOCs:

$$ \frac{\alpha}{x-1} = p \lambda$$

$$ \frac{\beta}{y-1} = q \lambda$$

$$ px+qy = m$$

I tried to solve the system above and then my plan was to multiply $x^*,y^*$ with $p$ and $q$ but that gives me different consumption function. Book has a hint that I should solve for $px$ and $qy$:

$$px = pa + \frac{\alpha}{\lambda}$$

$$qy = qb + \frac{\beta}{\lambda}$$

Then the book hints I should use budget constraint to eliminate lambda so I plug it there:|

$$ pa + \frac{\alpha}{\lambda} + qb + \frac{\beta}{\lambda}  = m $$

$$ \lambda = \frac{\alpha + \beta}{m- pa - qb} $$

When I plug the solution for lambda back to equation for $px$ I just get:

$$ px^* = pa + \frac{\alpha m - \alpha pa - \alpha bq}{\alpha +\beta} $$

And this is again not the consumption expenditure function the textbook says I should get. I don't get why I can't end with the same consumption expenditure as the book. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: As $\alpha + \beta = 1$, I think these are indeed the same solutions.

Comment: @tdm I don't get it, can you please explain why?

Comment: If you put $\alpha + \beta = 1$ in your solution, you get $px = pa + \alpha m - \alpha(pa + bq)$ as in the assignment. There is a typo though, because $1 b$ should be $q b$.

Comment: @tdm ooooo I see now, I am so dumb... if you want you can post it as an answer I will accept it. Yes, that was just typo it was qb

Comment: No problem. By the way, the utility function in you example is called a Stone-Geary utility function [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Geary_utility_function). It is very similar to a Cobb-Douglas utilities function, with the addition of subsistence levels $a$ and $b$ that provide the minimal levels of both goods that need to be consumed.

Comment: @tdm thanks for all the info